# Generic indexed type value in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

### Targets

Replace `any` to appropriate generic in below type definitions:

```js
export type GraphQL_OperationSpecification = {
  variables: GraphQL_OperationVariablesSpecification;
  // off-topic omit
};


export type GraphQL_OperationVariablesSpecification = { 
  [parameterName: string]: GraphQL_OperationVariableSpecification; 
};


export type GraphQL_OperationVariableSpecification = {
  //                                      Here ↓    Here ↓
  transformationFunction?: (requestParameter: any) => any;
  //                                      Here ↓
  mustSubmitIf?: (normalizedRequestParameter: any) => boolean;
    //                                         Here ↓
  transformToNullIf?: (normalizedRequestParameter: any) => boolean;
  // off-topic omit
};
```

such as below code will be compiled without errors:

```js
export const graphQL_OperationSpecification: GraphQL_OperationSpecification = {
  variables: {
    targetPaginationPageNumber__numerationFrom0: {
      // Assume that API wants page number from 0, not from 1.
      // However here both parameter and return value are number
      transformationFunction(pageNumber__numerationFrom1: number): number { return pageNumber__numerationFrom1 - 1; }
    },
    itemsCountPerPaginationPage: 
      // Assume that we are accepting string from UI but API needs number
      transformationFunction(stringifiedItemsCountPerPaginationPage: string): number { return String(stringifiedItemsCountPerPaginationPage); }
    }
  }
};
```

### Problem

For `GraphQL_OperationVariableSpecification`, everything is trivial:

```js
export type GraphQL_OperationVariableSpecification<RequestParameterForUI, RequestParameterForAPI> = {
  transformationFunction?: (requestParameter: RequestParameterForUI) => RequestParameterForAPI;
  mustSubmitIf?: (normalizedRequestParameter: RequestParameterForUI) => boolean;
  transformToNullIf?: (normalizedRequestParameter: RequestParameterForUI) => boolean;
};
```

Problems begins here:

```js
export type GraphQL_OperationVariablesSpecification = { 
  [parameterName: string]: GraphQL_OperationVariableSpecification<RequestParameterForUI, RequestParameterForAPI>; 
};
```

Now `GraphQL_OperationVariablesSpecification` needs 2 generic parameters too!
But we does not know at advance, which specific type will be the `RequestParameterForUI` and `RequestParameterForAPI`.

If we add two parameters to `GraphQL_OperationVariablesSpecification`, `GraphQL_OperationSpecification`  will required them too. But even if I add generic parameters wherever required:

```js
export type GraphQL_OperationSpecification<RequestParameterForUI, RequestParameterForAPI> = {
  variables: GraphQL_OperationVariablesSpecification<RequestParameterForUI, RequestParameterForAPI>;
};


export type GraphQL_OperationVariablesSpecification<RequestParameterForUI, RequestParameterForAPI> = {
  [parameterName: string]: GraphQL_OperationVariableSpecification<RequestParameterForUI, RequestParameterForAPI>;
};

export const graphQL_OperationSpecification: GraphQL_OperationSpecification<number | string, number> = {
  variables: {
    targetPaginationPageNumber__numerationFrom0: {
      transformationFunction(pageNumber__numerationFrom1: number): number { return pageNumber__numerationFrom1 - 1; }
    },
    itemsCountPerPaginationPage: 
        transformationFunction(stringifiedItemsCountPerPaginationPage: string): number { return String(stringifiedItemsCountPerPaginationPage); }
    }
  }
};
```

it will not solve the problem:

```
TS2322: Type '(pageNumber__numerationFrom1: number) => number' is not assignable to
 type '(requestParameter: string | number) => number'.
  Types of parameters 'pageNumber__numerationFrom1' and 'requestParameter' are inco
mpatible.
    Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  > 38 |         transformationFunction(pageNumber__numerationFrom1: number): numbe
r { return pageNumber__numerationFrom1 - 1; }
       |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In the case of `pageNumber__numerationFrom1`, it's number and nothing else. `stringifiedItemsCountPerPaginationPage` is string and nothing else. But how to explain it to TypeScript?

Comment: Where I believe you are being tripped up is here, `export const graphQL_OperationSpecification: GraphQL_OperationSpecification<number | string, number> = {`. What you might want to do is use a type assertion to override the above which would be telling TypeScript to just believe you when you say that it is indeed a `number`. Maybe, `transformationFunction(pageNumber__numerationFrom1) as number`. To sure about the accuracy of the syntax, but the idea is to override TypeScript and tell it whatever you get back from this is going to be a number, just trust me. May still have downside however.

Comment: @Daniel, thank you for the comment. But for information quantity, I'll start the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your last snippet so it type-checks: [TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDyYDKKDGAeABQBo4AlAPjgF44BvAKDjgDcBDKAS1YCMAbYAM4AuOADV22YPmJlyAbnoBfBfVCRYCZKnFRJ0khWp1GcANph2rALbAYwKADlrwEQJicAdgHMAuiIAqUKweAnqEBvJKKmrQ8EgocIHBobjhskYMTO7JAGbQViIAFGAiBACU1JSkSvSq4LFwOBAh8BBYuCIYYR4Arlbc9iRunl5wAD5wvf32lDSZLOxcfIIi81nsXrYErF6rJkxZQSF5UFbFFbRwULY9UB5wYHAAtHAAjHJwivuf3yQcdlYBABhCA9DwwPYHA7ZY75c50K43O5wTDuDjec4fL5Q7E-ZRAA).

But basically, instead of `GraphQL_OperationSpecification<number | string, number>`, you want `GraphQL_OperationSpecification<number, string | number>`.